# matlab scatter3 plot real and imaginary parts over frequency

Tags: matlab, plot

I've got to vectors called ttre and ttim which contain real and imaginary data over a frequency (from 1 to 64). The fields are looking like this:

```
ttim    64x10100 single
ttre    64x10100 single
```

I can easily make a 2D scatter plot of a certain row by using the command

```
scatter(ttim(40,:),ttre(40,:))
```

Now, I would like to display all data in a 3D scatter plot where X=real values, Y=imaginary values and Z=[1...64]
I created an array for Z with the number 1 to 64 and copied it to make it the same size as the other variables, by:

```
z=(1:64)'
z=repmat(z,1,10100)

result:
z     64x10100 double
```

When I try to plo a 3D scatter plot now, I get the error "Vectors x,yu,z must be of the same size"...however, as far as I understand, they are of the same size.

```
>> scatter3(ttim,ttre,z)
Error using scatter3 (line 64)
X, Y and Z must be vectors of the same length.
```

I hope that someone could point me into the right direction here.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scatter3` needs points to plot, so `x`,`y`and `z` should be 1xN , where N is the amount of points your are plotting. I dont know what your data is, so unfortunately I can not help more. Maybe `scatter3(ttim(:),ttre(:),z(:))` works, but I do not recommend it for the huge amount of data you have, it may crash your computer.

However, maybe `z=1:64` is not the best option.  It means that you will have 64 layers (like floors from a building) of scattered data, not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Words out of my mouth. They do this in the [`scatter3` examples](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#examples)

Comment: Thank you. That actually solved the problem. You are right that the amount of data point is much too high. I just wanted to have a quick look to see the data is right. Thank you again.